# AVAudioEngine inputNode call throws error

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite, avaudioengine

I'm developing a simple desktop app which simultaneously plays and records audio. All was going well, until I somehow worked a bug into it - now every time I try to call the `AVAudioEngine`'s `inputNode` or `mainMixer`, it throws an error.

I've got a property `@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAudioEngine *engine;` in my header, and in my `init` method implementation the following code, which throws on the `inputNode` call:

```
if (self = [super init]) {
   _engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

   AVAudioInputNode *node = [_engine inputNode];
}
return self;
```

Setting a breakpoint on all exception results in the top of the call stack looking like this:

```
#0  0x00007fff8ba19ab7 in __cxa_throw ()
#1  0x0000000108123779 in AUHAL::GetAudioChannelLayout(unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioChannelLayout*, unsigned char&) ()
#2  0x00000001081183c6 in AUBase::DispatchGetPropertyInfo(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int&, unsigned char&) ()
#3  0x00000001081cdf66 in AUMethodGetPropertyInfo(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned char*) ()
```

I had this working previously, so I assume I am forgetting something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for some reason, removing the `All Exceptions` breakpoint resolved the issue.

Either there is a bug in XCode or AVFoundation, or I don't know how to use XCode as well as I should.

Comment: And seemingly 6.3 also.

Comment: FWIW, since the exception being thrown is a C++ Exception, you can change the "All Exceptions" breakpoint to "All Objective-C Exceptions" if you still want Objective-C Exceptions (to do so, right click on the "All Exceptions" breakpoint and choose Edit Breakpoint, then change Exception to Objective-C instead of All).

Comment: I'm getting this error, but removing the breakpoint just means I don't hear the sound :(

Comment: @ash - I haven't looked at this in ages, but maybe try adding a ```sleep``` or doing something else to prevent the program from finishing.

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out my issue was completely unconnected. It seems that loading sounds using `AVAudioSource(named:)` doesn't work for loading sounds from an asset catalogue on Mac OS - at least not as far as I could see - so I moved my sound files into the app bundle and used `AVAudioSource(fileNamed:)` instead and that solved the problem. It would have helped if the failing method returned nil or threw an error, but the code didn't go bad until much later so it was hard to diagnose the issue.